# Check if set image is the same as image in cache

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I am looking for an inexpensive way to know if the image set in my UITableViewCell is the same as the one i try to set from my cache.

Since i have reusable cells i need to be able to change the image when i reuse the cell.

Problem is, the image for the first cells are set twice and it is provoking a blink which i would like to avoid.

I have to check for equality between "imageView.image" and the image retrieved from the cache but it isn't working.

Any clue?

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: prevent my images from reloading if they are the same

Comment: did you use model class ?

Comment: I use realmswift

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to find a workaround for the blinking issue, perhaps try to debug why that is happening instead.

Ideally, you should use `prepareForReuse` and clear out the image every time the cell gets reused. Also, if the image is cached, it should be set once only, and immediately (not after a while like in the first instance where there's a miss in the cache and you have to perform a network call).

If you really must check if the image is the same, you could compare the URL of the image in question, both `URL` and `String` are `Equatable` and could be used to uniquely identify images.

Comment: That would be the same as setting an isSet boolean.
There is no possibility to check the url of an image that is already set since i have a DidSet on the main property which i use to set everything properly.

Using prepareForReuse and/or clearing the image isn't working, first thing i tried.
This is happening because ios is calling cellForRow at indexPath each time viewWillAppear is called, don't see how i could debug that

Comment: An isSet boolean doesn't seem to be exactly the same thing, the boolean would only tell whether the image is set or not, but not with which image. If `URL` was part of your `viewModel` object, you could compare it with the previous `viewModel` used to set up the cell before, thus avoiding setting it again with the same image.

Comment: Also, I've just tried a sample master-detail project and when popping the detail view controller, `viewWillAppear` gets called for the master view controller, but that does not trigger calls to `cellForRowAt indexPath`, so something else in your code must be triggering it.

Comment: Tried to use the data from the model to by comparing the id, id is the same, data is not reset but the cells are reload, this is kinda meh.
Seems the culprit is elsewhere and i will have to investigate further.
Thanks for your time though